# Virtual Box 4.2 does not install in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

I need to run windows apps in ubuntu 13.04 but everything is going wrong. I tried to install wine but it failed. Giving up and switching to VIRTUAL BOX did not help either. I downloaded Virtualbox 4.2 and when tried to install through software center it gives error

```
"Dependency is not satisfiable: libsdl1.2debian(>=1.2.11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Vvirtualbox this way.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Error message

Comment: Can you post an image of the exact error?

Comment: Ahhh!   It says you need 10 reputations to post images

Comment: Yes I have got it! Thanks for you time. I changed the server from Local Pakistan Server to Main Server and its now Working.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You will see it gonna say some following dependencies didn't met,then

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

all these worked for me . I had a similar problem like this . I fixed numerous issues using this commands . They are really helpful .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your machine is up to date first by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

My first recommendation would be to go through the Virtual Box website. I have included the link for you.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Be sure you are downloading the correct version for your processor type and you shouldn't run into any problems.

Please let us know if you do and we can then try to advise you further.

Comment: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.  This is the error message displayed when running above command.

Comment: That is nothing to worry about at the moment. Move on to downloading the correct version of Virtual Box and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yes I have got it! Thanks for you time. I changed the server from Local Pakistan Server to Main Server and its now Working

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue while installing virtual box in 14.04 , on installing via terminal it gave the error,that you have held broken packages (depend:libgsoap4 but it is not installable),solved by selecting a different server and selecting all the options in software and updates.

Then tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

and it did work and installed virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error today on a clean install of 13.04. After reading this thread did the following:

- changed software server for 'Software & Updates' from 'Russia' to 'Main'.
- ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

That's it - VirtualBox installed without a hitch. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, try use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, but dont work.

On my Ubuntu was solved by installing using `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian`. After this installation everything works as it should ...

Comment: Your last sentence didn't get translated.